Blazor: Reference to child page displayed by RenderFragment Body
If I create a Blazor project from the Visual Studio templates, in the MainLayout.razor there is a
<article class="content px-4">
    @Body
</article>

part. The @Body is a RenderFragment where all child pages are displayed.
If I insert a child razor page directly, I can set a reference like this:
<ChildPage @ref="child"></ChildPage>

and use this in the code to e.g. update the child page:
ChildPage child { get; set; }

child.Update();

How can I get a reference to a child page in the MainLayout.razor to e.g. reload the child page?

You don't normally manually trigger a render like that.  If you explain why you want to call Update on ChildPage from the layout, we can probably provide mainstream solution to your use case.

Well, in the child page I have e.g. a chart that I need to refresh using updated data.
If I just call StateHasChanged() in the parent, the chart in the child page is not updated.

You should do all this in the Chart page.  What mechanism triggers an update and calling StateHasChanged?  Add some more code to your question.

I do calculations in the parent (MainLayout.razor). The results are relevant for many child pages. For example time marching steps are performed. At a new time step, I need to tell the child to update a chart with the new data.

I believe you might be looking for Cascading Values/Parameters here, that way you should be able to pass whatever data you have on Layout level down to any page requiring it as a parameter -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/cascading-values-and-parameters
Alternative approach would be to look into state management -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management

You could try create a TriggerService like following.
    public class TriggerService
    {
        // Use Func<Task> to allow for async methods
        public  Func<Task>? OnTriggerAsync { get; set; }

        // Trigger the async method
        public  async Task TriggerMethodAsync()
        {
            if (OnTriggerAsync != null)
            {
                await OnTriggerAsync.Invoke();
            }
        }
    }

builder.Services.AddScoped<TriggerService>();

ChildPage.razor (register the trigger event to the update method)
@inject TriggerService _triggerSerivce
ChildValue: @childValue
@code {
    private string childValue { get; set; } = "old value";
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _triggerSerivce.OnTriggerAsync += Update;
    }
    private async Task Update()
    {
        // Simulate asynchronous getting new data
        await Task.Delay(500);
        childValue = "new value";
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}

After these,  you could call following at any place to update the child data without using reference.
await TriggerService.TriggerMethodAsync();

